# Why am i getting "/RCS/trunk,v: No such file or directory" when i try to checkout SVN?

Tags: svn, ssh, svn-checkout, rcs

I tried to checkout a project from the server to my local computer with svn+ssh command but i get a strange error:
`/RCS/trunk,v: No such file or directory`

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: What is the svn command you are using to checkout the project.

Comment: sudo co svn+ssh://pepe@1.... OH i get it. i missed the 'svn' after sudo. damn, stupid. Thanx jgifford25

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the command was:

```
sudo co svn+ssh://pepe@1
```

instead of

```
sudo svn co svn+ssh://pepe@1
```

Answer (score 0):

So i had the issue like

```
 git RCS/co,v: no such file or directory
```

and solved after closing the active Linux shell. Hope it is picking from temp storage files.